# I would like to create an efficient Bigtable row key

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I would like to create an optimal row key in Bigtable. I have a table `channel_data` with 3 columns: `channel_id`,`date`,`fan_count`.

| channel_id | date | fan_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 5000 |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 6000 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-03-02 | 300 |
| 3 | 2022-03-03 | 1000 |

Users of our application can set up brands/buckets by adding multiple channels. Users can choose any random `channel_id`.

I want to design an efficient row key to fetch aggregated `fan_count` in a date range for a brand.

Let's say the user creates a brand with `channel_id` 1 and 3 and wish to see sum of all fans for the time period 2022-03-01 to 2022-03-03

The result should be 5000+6000+1000=12000

Comment: user can choose start date and end date to see aggregated fan_count

Comment: Can you clarify the rowkey design you are suggesting? It is unclear from your post

Comment: @BillyJacobson Please check. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. Because you're looking to do queries based on date, you should probably make that the end part of your rowkey so you can scope down by brand first. You could also use [timestamped cells](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/garbage-collection#timestamps) to store multiple values for each channel. Perhaps a week or month of data, so it is grouped together in that way, but this isn't necessary.

Perhaps a rowkey like `channel_id/yyyy-mm-dd` is what you'd want. You can choose to store the date and channel info in the table, but it isn't necessary since you'd have it in your ids. You can just treat Bigtable like a key/value store in this instance which might be more optimal depending on your scenario.

If you choose to store a month of data per row, you would just make the rowkey something like `channel_id/yyyy-mm` and just timestamp each value for the day.

Either way for your queries, if you need multiple channels, then you could just do multiple reads or a multi-prefix scan. Let me know if this helps clarify the schema design and if you have more questions.

Comment: If I use `channel_id/yyyy-mm-dd` for the above-mentioned example of aggregation. Will there be a performance downgrade because channel_id 1 and 2 should be retrieved from two different row keys and be aggregated?

Comment: I think you should be fine since you need to get the same amount of rows either way. If you have channels that would be always queried together or certain groups, perhaps you would want to do something else, but I think erring on the simpler side is smart to start and test with and you can modify if you find it isn't giving you the throughput you want. Because you can do a multi-prefix read, you can also execute the in one call, so you don't have to make multiple requests yourself which is a good thing